# Increment field only if command on array was successful

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema like this:

```
var ClassSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    kids: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Kid' }],
    kidsCount: { type: Number, default: 0}
});
```

Now I want to `pull` a Kid from the array and decrement the counter, only if that Kid existed in the array. Can it be done in one single command?

I have tried this:

```
Class.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id:classId, kids:kidId  },
    { $pull:{ kids:kidId }, $inc:{ kidsCount:-1 } },
    function(err, updatedClass){
        // ...
    }
);
```

but `kidsCount` is always decremented, no matter if the Kid is found or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using the wrong method. [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) takes **only** the `_id` as the first parameter, so you want [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) instead, which takes a full conditions object.

```
Class.update(
    { _id:classId, kids:kidId  },
    { $pull:{ kids:kidId }, $inc:{ kidsCount:-1 } },
    function(err, numAffected){
        // ...
    }
);
```

But of course you **don't** get the updated document in the callback. You would have to find, if you really needed it here.

Comment: That was it. I added the `kids:kidId` condition afterwards and I didn't think about the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After Neil's answer, I've discovered [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) which is even a better solution in my case. You get the modified document in the callback as with `findByIdAndUpdate`:

```
Class.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id:classId, kids:kidId  },
    { $pull:{ kids:kidId }, $inc:{ kidsCount:-1 } },
    function(err, updatedClass){
      // ...
    }
);
```

Comment: I missed that. Good pickup.